# Custom emoticons in Empathy

Tags: 12.04, empathy

I'm trying to use Empathy instead of Kopete, I want to have access to my custom emoticons which I also used in Kopete. I installed them seperately and my contacts could receive them.

Is that kind of thing possible to do in Empathy? Besides the standard emoticons, can new emoticons be added and seen by other contacts?

I'm using Empathy 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Empathy does not support custom emoticons. You would be better off using [pidgin [image: Install pidgin]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pidgin).

Comment: Hello Roland, I wonder why Empathy replaced Piding in the first place. What does Empathy have that Pidgin doesn't? Anyway, thanks. Guess that's what I will do.

Comment: @KnightofZero mostly Empathy has better integration with the OS because it's part of Gnome, and also Empathy has better chat theme capabilities, and a better video chat interface. That's about it.

Comment: I find that it works better with facebook, and I personally prefer the chat window, I think pidgin is ugly...